# using HTML div and CSS

Tags: html, css

So, this is the HTML code

```
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="header">
        <input name="1" value="1" disabled  />
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS-File:

```
.header {
   background-color: yellow;
   color: green
}
```

The problem i have, is that the CSS code isn't changing the HTML, so i made a quick test and put the CSS code in the HTML file and it worked.

I also know that, if i use "id" insead of "class" it works, but the task is to not change the HTML file

My problem is that i don't want the CSS code in the HTML file, is that possible?

**edit: i just tried it online an it worked, so it seems to be a problem of webstorm**

Comment: Are you sure your path to `style.css` is correct? Does the console show any 404s?

Comment: Please post a fiddle containing your test code so we can clearly see your entire test code.

Comment: Is the CSS you posted the entirety of the CSS you're using?

Comment: yes, i also made a test if the CSS file was properly linked

Comment: I don't know if this is an issue, but it looks like your body tag isn't closed.

Comment: i am using Webstorm, i just tried it online and it works, so it seems to be a problem of webstorm

Answer (score 0):

Since you set in your HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

your `style.css` file must be in the same folder as your HTML file.

Also, `;` are missing at the end of the `color: green` in your CSS file, so your CSS need to looks like:

```
.header {
   background-color: yellow;
   color: green;
}
```

and your body tag isn't closed, so your HTML need to looks like:

```
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="header">
        <input name="1" value="1" disabled  />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The last statement in a CSS block doesn't need a closing semi-colon, but it is good practice to have one there.